# how to get json data in export const LANDMARKS : Landmark[] = this.myobj; using nativscript

Tags: angularjs, json, nativescript

I am calling an API which gives me a JSON array so I want to assign the returned data to `LANDMARKS` variable.

Source Code:

```
export const LANDMARKS : Landmark[] = this.myobj;
   console.log(this.myItems);


 fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {this.myItems =  json;

  console.log(this.myItems);
        **const myobj = this.myItems**
  // return myobj;
}

  );
```

Comment: So you want to assign `this.myItems` to Landmark[]?

Comment: Yes this.myItems to Landmark[]

Comment: if you getting the response from API then try with:  LANDMARKS = this.myItems

Comment: Yes i tride .then(json => {this.myItems =  json;

  console.log(this.myItems);enter code here
        **const myobj = this.myItems** data proprly display hear   but not gatting in Landmark[]

Comment: and pls format the code and remove commented code

Comment: export const LANDMARKS : Landmark[] =  this.myItems;
       console.log(this.myItems);
     
        fetch('http://www.fillingshare.com/sms_app/nativ.php')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {this.myItems =  json;
      
      console.log(this.myItems);
            
       
    }
    
      );

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
export const LANDMARKS: Landmark[] = [];

fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
        var myItems = json;
        this.LANDMARKS = myItems;
        console.log('--Landmark List--',this.LANDMARKS);
    });
```

Comment: Not Working CONSOLE LOG file:///app/mock-landmarks.js:168:12: undefined

Comment: try console the value of `json`? what it is?

Comment: console.log('--Landmark List--',this.LANDMARKS); in this console value can fatch proply

Comment: Ok then? that is what you required?

Comment: export const LANDMARKS: Landmark[] = [];  
  // if i print in this console data can not be fatch console.log(this.LANDMARKS);
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then(response => response.json())

Comment: export const LANDMARKS: Landmark[] = [];
    console.log(this.LANDMARKS);

Comment: Now, what is the problem?